# why my code not work -what says on the terminal?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, terminal, syntax-error

hello there I am trying to run this code >>

```
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] p1={2,3,4};
    double[] p2={2,3};
    int maxlentharr;
    if (p1.length > p2.length) {
           maxlentharr = p1.length;
    } else {
           maxlentharr = p2.length;
    }
    double[] Array = new double[maxlentharr];
    for (int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
           Array[i] = 0;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < p1.length; k++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < p2.length; j++) {
                  Array[j + k] += (p1[j] * p2[j]);

           }
    }
    for (double element: Array) {
           System.out.println("------------------");
           System.out.println(element);
    }
```

}
}

but it seems not works, I do not see any error on the code but here what I get on the terminal>>

[image: see the terminal message her]

[![here][2]][2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Here there's a issue: p1[j]

   ```
   for (int k = 0; k < p1.length; k++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < p2.length; j++) {
           Array[j + k] += (p1[j] * p2[j]);
       }
   }
   ```

   You are cycling over p1 using the index [j] you created for p2. This might
   cause errors. I think what you wanted to do is p1[k] * p2[j]
2. Another issue might be the fact that Array dimension is not j+k but actually only the biggest between j and k

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks for the edit, I was having problems fixing it back

Answer (score 0):

Array[j + k] += (p1[j] * p2[j])

should be

Array[j + k] += (p1[k] * p2[j])